# How to differentiate usage and inheritance in a layered architecture?

Tags: archunit

I'm trying to validate the following dependencies:

[image: relationships]

[Source](https://www.planttext.com/api/plantuml/png/RD6nJiGm30RWFKzXYRbTsD6XcvaE9dI3bRZNgAaJEIcd2dWo1Xw9Ly2q75VHRh6TB_wbV7ryxd91AKCVZ6cz8w0-bH4QJy7bPQUdqaPjvSvpGi4UWcSgOoA8egF504NY-R7rjcFA6MwDIMWxF16WmrH803CqzM_nQW1iGBruRsqSkEmZ5uaXa9ZtAyqaBzxIJ2_5rHw8tKDa6W_pQ4cJ1fpTTFf1ddLpW_h47tpAjCSymLKGg9vlJaB4HnVFNDsjbVaV0EeB6LBzjYNMMvG8kMd7DbajgMOnfCrCE-teptu3003__mC0)

In this picture, red relationships are forbidden, green relationships are allowed:

- no class in the adapter package can inherit from a class in the port package;
- any class in the adapter package can use (e.g. have a field) a class in the port package;
- no class in the service package can use (e.g. have a field) from a class in the port package;
- any class in the service package can inherit a class in the port package;

If possible I'd like to add these validations to Layered Architecture.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`LayeredArchitecture`](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.tngtech.archunit/archunit/latest/com/tngtech/archunit/library/Architectures.LayeredArchitecture.html) considers *all* [dependencies](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.tngtech.archunit/archunit/latest/com/tngtech/archunit/core/domain/Dependency.html) between layers. You cannot forbid inheritance, but allow access – nor vice versa. I recommend to define individual specific rules instead:

```java
@ArchTest
ArchRule adapter_should_not_inherit_from_port = noClasses()
    .that().resideInAPackage("….adapter")
    .should().beAssignableTo(JavaClass.Predicates.resideInAPackage("….port"));

@ArchTest
ArchRule service_should_not_access_port = noClasses()
    .that().resideInAPackage("….service")
    .should().accessClassesThat().resideInAPackage("….port");
```